# laravel how to validate as equal to a variable

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-validation

in laravel validation (registering) i want to compare one of the fields with a php variable (it should be equal with that)

how can i do this?

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{

    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'phone' => 'required|min:10|max:11|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
        'password' => 'required',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required',
        'user_captcha' => 'required'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: you mean something like this? 'name' => 'equalto:$varable', it just an example for understanding

Comment: Yes  exactly i need this

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can do it for example for name field like this:

```
$variable = "something"
return Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => [
        'required',
        Rule::in([$variable]),
    ],
    'phone' => 'required|min:10|max:11|unique:users',
    'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
    'password' => 'required',
    'password_confirmation' => 'required',
    'user_captcha' => 'required'
]);
```

Remember to import Rule Class (use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;)

You can get more info in: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-in

**EDIT**

As suggested by @patricus, you can also concatenate the variable

```
$variable = "something"
return Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => 'required|in:'.$variable,
    'phone' => 'required|min:10|max:11|unique:users',
    'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
    'password' => 'required',
    'password_confirmation' => 'required',
    'user_captcha' => 'required'
]);
```

**EDIT2**

If you have a variable that is an array:

```
$variable = ['one','two'];
return Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => 'required|in:'.implode(",", $variable),
    'phone' => 'required|min:10|max:11|unique:users',
    'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
    'password' => 'required',
    'password_confirmation' => 'required',
    'user_captcha' => 'required'
]);
```

Or

```
$variable = ['one','two']
return Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => [
        'required',
        Rule::in($variable),
    ],
    'phone' => 'required|min:10|max:11|unique:users',
    'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
    'password' => 'required',
    'password_confirmation' => 'required',
    'user_captcha' => 'required'
]);
```

Comment: Given the simple use of a variable, it would probably look better just to do: `'name' => 'required|in:'.$variable,`

Comment: @leonardo and patricus my fiels is captcha i test your two ways and i will fill whole form correctly but i have just one error : user_captcha
:
["validation.required"]

Comment: print the $data variable please

Comment: its ok. its an array and everything is right. just the captcha validation (in:) not working (just required will working)

Comment: the problem was from sending my data from form and ajax. sovled with in: . thank you. voted up

Comment: for those who have the error 'App\Http\Controllers\Validator' not found, try:              "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;"

Comment: that edit version didn't work for me though. 1st is ok

Comment: Is it right, that  $variable will never be showed to user ?

Comment: Or even `'name' => "required|in:$variable"`